# Comparison Error While Converting C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am in the process of converting some c# code to that of VB.NET...I am running into error at the following

C#

```
if (bytes[i - 1] == ' ')
{
  returnValue.Append("=20");
}
else if (bytes[i - 1] == '\t')
{
  returnValue.Append("=09");
}
```

VB.NET

```
If bytes(i - 1) = " "C Then <==error Operator "=" is not defined for types 'Byte' and 'Char'

   returnValue.Append("=20")
ElseIf bytes(i - 1) = ControlChars.Tab Then <==error Operator "=" is not defined for types 'Byte' and 'Char'
   returnValue.Append("=09")
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the actual problems lies with the initial comparison.  You are trying to compare a `byte` to a `char`.  Try converting the `byte` to a `char` first.

```
if char(bytes(i - 1)) = " "C Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try using

```
Convert.ToChar(bytes(i - 1)) = " "C
```

or

```
bytes(i - 1) = Convert.ToByte(" "C)
```